# iOS StoryBoard with some Portrait views and some Landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, orientation, uistoryboard

I have a story board based iPhone application where the majority of the views are in Portrait mode, and should only ever be shown in portrait, due to the nature of the content. But then I have one view which should only ever be in landscape - how can I ensure that views are only displayed in the correct orientation?

I tried adding a second storyboard with the main storyboard set to Portrait orientation and the new storyboard set to landscape but if you launch the landscape view it appears in portrait mode. Can I forcibly rotate the view to landscape in viewWillAppear?

I tried setting the Target's build setting, orientation value to 'Portrait' and 'Landscape Left' but now been my portrait-only storyboard will auto rotate and screw up it's layout.

So, basically, how can I force a view to allow only one particular orientation (portrait for most of view, landscape for just one)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one storyboard will do this. You need to do that ..

1- Go to inspector and select the view and then uncheck the autolayout.

2- Then click on size inspector top right on xcode file.

3- select your controlls one by one and resize them from Left,Right,Top and Bottom.

4- After that run your project.and see what happen....